# Strategy to store settings info in Blazor app

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to develop an app that I need to store API tokens from various services that the app needs to use to pull information from.  This app has a single user, so I'm a little confused on how I should best store the API keys to these services for this user.  Storing in a DB would be find, but I'm not sure how I should structure the database to store this single record for each API token.  Should I have an APIs table and store a single record in that table for this single user?  It seems to me there's probably a separate/better way to store this type of information for the user.

I hope I'm asking my question clearly!

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

First off, it would be helpful if you could be more precise about how you use Blazor and which version. Are you using Blazor Server, WebAssembly, or the newest Blazor United? If only one user is using it, do you host Blazor on their machine or in the cloud? Nevertheless I would try to give my suggestions.

1. For tokens known at startup:

   I do not know If this is a solution that you are looking for, but I use Key Vaults for storing my secure data. For example I add this code in the startup :

   ```
    var AZURE_CRED = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, AZURE_CRED);
   ```

   You need to add Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets , Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets and Microsoft.Extensions.Azure package.

   When I inject IConfiguration configuration, to access my data, I only need to get it like this :  configuration["My_Key1"], configuration["My_Key2"] ....

   Unfortunately, for this solution, you need to set up a Key Vault in the Azure cloud. Furthermore, the machine you are running the program on must be in the Azure space with Identity enabled, or have a configured profile for DefaultAzureCredential() to work properly.

   You can also try other vaults from AWS or any other provider, maybe there are easier to implement for you. The point is, this is a safe solution and it is easy for you to manage and change keys when Api tokens change.
2. For tokens that are received while program is running:

   Depending on whether you are using only Blazor Server or WebAssembly, you have different options. For Blazor Server, you can use, for example, ProtectedSessionStorage.
3. If you have local database I assume it's fine to store API keys there.You can find out, if your DB provider have JSON documents support, so you can store Tokens in Json, and load it into configuration from DB.

I hope that will help you, but further explanation would be welcome.